# .htaccess redirecting to https excluding one path

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm redirecting my hole website (WordPress) from HTTP to HTTPS, and I want to exclude one path from that.

That path is excluded from that rule, but for some reason it's being redirected to the home path (http://mywebsite.com/excludedpath -> https://mywebsite.com/index.php) instead of just not redirecting it. All other paths are redirected properly to HTTPS.

The .htaccess I'm using is:

```
RewriteOptions inherit
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

# Block via User Agent
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (libwww|EvilBot|ScumSucker|FakeAgent) [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule (.*) - [F,L]
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule ^((?!excludedpath).)*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress



# BEGIN GZIP
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
</IfModule>
# END GZIP

#Image Expires Tag Test
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

Am I missing something? Why is the excluded path redirected to the website's home page?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to exclude a path from using https?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson It's for a test page where users are able to input their own content URLs. I want them to be able to input HTTP and HTTPS links, and in order to be able to use them with JavaScript the page needs to use HTTP or the browser will block loading the HTTP content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `RewriteCond` to check if the request uri is starting with `/excludedpath`.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^[A-Z]{3,}\s/excludedpath/ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Comment: I have tried that, but the behaviour is the same, the excludedpath is redirected to the website's home page. I'm not sure where this behaviour can be added, since if I remove the redirect to HTTPS, both the HTTP and HTTPS versions of the page work.

Comment: then you might need to check the `THE_REQUEST` variable, i've just updated the answer